# Compare two std::strings in c++

Tags: c++, string

Is this comparison possible to do in C++?

```
std::string name = "John";

if (name == "Tom")
   flag = true;
else
   flag = false;
```

Comment: Why not `flag = name == "Tom";`??

Comment: Yes, [you can](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).

Comment: @KerrekSB: I personally would use `flage = (name == "Tom");`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it is, because `std::string` overloads `operator ==` for `const char*`.

Alternatively, you can just write

```
flag = name == "Tom";
```

or use `std::string::compare` (returns `0` if the strings match)

Answer (score -7):

To compare srtings in c++, I recommend you to use STRCMP from:

```
#include <string.h>
....
STRCMP(name,"Tom"); // This will return 0 if they are equal
```

so you should use it as:

```
if (STRCMP(name,"Tom")==0)
  flag = true;
else
  flag = false;
```

remember to use #include < string.h>

Comment: Why would be better an _old fashioned_ function or macro or wathever `STRCMP` is than the `std::basic_string` comparision operators?

Comment: there is no such thing as STRCMP in standard C++.

Comment: because it's more human friendly, and when you are learning how to program from the scratch (unless you have a gifted mind) a function with an example it's the best so you can understand how a computer works

Comment: @Sascuash: it seems to me that most people find op== more human friendly, also given that if he meant `strcmp` from C, the call would look different (besides that it is more inefficient and can even lead to wrong results, depending on the contents of `name`)

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I do accept that strcmp if more inefficient, but the problems you can have are the same as the ones you can get using flag = name == "Tom"; as you can mix = with == while writing it and that it's almost impossible to find. Dont't you think?

Comment: @Sascuash: not at all, I personally can clearly distinguish = and ==. And if you can not, you can still write `if(name=="Tom")`. And even if it was, this still does not resolve the cases where both lead to different results.

Comment: @Sascuash, first, STRCMP is a macro, defined (if I remember correctly) for Windows C++ libraries (i.e. not standard C++). Second, please don't recomment C string processing functions in C++ - they lead to bad/unsafe C++ coding and miss the advantages of modern C++ code (RAII comes to mind). String comparisons in C++ should be made using std::string (that is the reason std::string is there for).